# How do I efficiently grow bioluminescent algae?

Tags: botany, bioluminescence

I have 6 vials of Pyrocystis lunula that I would like to grow. What would be a more suitable container, a tank or a clear jar? Also, I would like to know what kind of nutrient solution to use. Is it possible to get them to reproduce at a rate that eventually there can be a whole tank full of them?

Comment: What sort of research have you done to try and answer your own question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with that particular species but dinoflagellates are often slow growing, very tricky to get to high densities and hard to maintain for a long time without proper experience and lab conditions.

If you still want to have a go I would recommend the following. Growth conditions are rather similar for most dinoflagellates: use a rotary shaker (gentle rotation) in a 12:12 day night regime, don't dilute to hard when subculturing and use standard F2 medium (see [link](https://ncma.bigelow.org/algal-recipes) for recipe). If you cannot get hold of seawater you can use saltwater aquarium salts such as Instant Ocean.

Most hate temperature changes so best to keep them at 18-21C

Comment: So I can just go to the beach and get some sea water from their?

Comment: You will have to sterilise it first (autoclave) and add nutrients such as iron, nitrate and phosphate. See the F2 recipe on the link provided